# Android, sending a voice message

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I’ve built an app for a client that basically sends a standard pre written SMS to the client of my client’s phone asking for them to get in contact. Now the client would like to be able to send a pre recorded voice message to an answering service with the touch of a button, can this be done, firstly from an Android phone.

I’m guessing it can be done because when I search for an answer all I can find are apps that someone else has written that do just that.

Sometimes development tutorials can be hard to find when it comes to apps as you just get a long list of people trying to sell their apps…lol.

Does anyone know of such a tutorial?r

Comment: Anyone have an idea, could you send a .wav or something as an attachment maybe???

Comment: +1 hopefully someone will find you an answer

Comment: @Hunt, the client decided to not follow the original plan so I didn’t have to try and implement it in the end. But while researching it I couldn’t find a way to do it. That was 5 months ago, maybe it can be done now?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but maybe could help

I once wrote an application like that for a particular answering service for a particular provider in my country.  To leave a message on their device I was basically required to compose an e-mail with a message recorded as an mp3 file and included as an attachment to the mail. I then send such mail to a specific mail address of their answering service. I had to supply credentials for the mail to be accepted. Such credentials (login/password) I obtained first by sending a specific port SMS to their service.

For composing mails with attachment I used an opensource IMAP client for Android (as a jar library added to my project). Don't rememeber which client it was but can find out.

I guess there's no common standard for that but basically all the answering services should do something similar.

Sorry if this info is too vague, I was just given the protocol of how that particular answering service was working and implemented accordingly.